# How to change added torrent file location for transmission-daemon

Tags: raspberry-pi, transmission, transmission-daemon

The transmission-daemon stores by default some temporary files and the added torrent files in the following directory:

```
/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/
```

Is it possible to set another directory?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `ln -s /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/ ~/MyAwesomeTransmissionConfigDirecotry` or whatnot? ;-)

You'll just probably need `sudo` to `ls` it :)